# Limit the maximum value returned for each row

Tags: mysql, max, row, limit

Assuming I have a table as follows:

```
|id | duration | timeout
=========================
| 1 |   100    |   0
| 2 |  12345   |   1
| 3 |   321    |   0
```

I would like to get the total duration, as well as the number of sessions and number of timeouts, like so:

```
SELECT count(id) session_count, sum(duration) duration, count(timeout) timeouts
```

**But** for any session that timed out, I need to limit the value to 1000. so my query should produce something like:

```
| session_count | duration | timeouts
=====================================
|     3         |  1421    |    1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SUM(IF(timeout = 1, 1000, duration)) AS duration`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go, also changed count(timeout) to sum(timeout)what the if does is check value of timeout if 0 then use duration, otherwise use 1000

```
SELECT COUNT(id) session_count, SUM(IF (timeout = 0, duration,1000)) duration, SUM(timeout) timeouts
```